# C# Random Seed Value of int.MinValue Unpredictable

Tags: c#, random, seed

So I am currently trying to test a function that uses a random function. In order to test it, I'm passing in a seed value to the C# Random function. (ie. System.Random)

My test cases involve using int.MaxValue and int.MinValue to get boundary testing. The max value of integer produces consistent and expected results. But when I try to use the min value the next keeps producing random results that are not predictable and therefore can't be tested.

I'm curious if this is expected or what the reasoning a seed is not producing predictable results. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Supplying the code for reference. The methods are array extensions that I use in order to shuffle the array into a random order. I'm using the random class in order to get varied results and passing in my seed as an optional parameter to allow testing.

```
public static void Shuffle<T>(this T[] array, int seedValue = -1)
{
   // Create the randomizer that will be needed
   Random random = seedValue >= 0 ? new Random(seedValue) : new Random();

   // Run the algorithm
   for (int i = array.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
   {
       // Get a random integer with a maximum of i
       int r = random.Next(i);

       // Swap the element at r with the element at i
       array.Swap(r, i);
   }
}

public static void Swap<T>(this T[] array, int indexOne, int indexTwo)
{
    // Check if the indices that we were passed are the same index
    if (indexOne == indexTwo)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Check that the first index is in range
    if (indexOne < 0 || indexOne >= array.Length)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("indexOne", "The first index provided is out of the range of the array provided.");
    }

    // Check that the second index is in range
    if (indexTwo < 0 || indexTwo >= array.Length)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("indexTwo", "The second index provided is out of the range of the array provided.");
    }

    // Swap the items
    T temp = array[indexOne];
    array[indexOne] = array[indexTwo];
    array[indexTwo] = temp;
}
```

So those are the methods that are being tested. I'm passing the minvalue into the Shuffle function. And upon further investigation for myself, it seems to be occuring with any negative value. It seems to produce inconsistent results. I am currently working in the .NET 2.0. Old version I know, but I'm working inside Unity.

Comment: This is unusual, according to the source code, it should behave exactly the same as for int.MaxValue - http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,bb77e610694e64ca

Comment: Can you post the code where you see this behaviour i.e. an MCVE? I can't reproduce this.

Comment: [Tried to reproduce](http://rextester.com/MRSA67340) but failed. Please add a [mcve].

Comment: Same here: tried to repro, but works fine. Can you show your code that demonstrates this, please? Also: tell us exactly what framework you are targeting and running on - it might matter (it might be an old bug that was fixed 10 years ago)

Comment: minimal code that shows it working for me: `var rand = new Random(int.MinValue); for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{ Console.WriteLine(rand.Next()); }` - same results each time for me

Comment: As an aside: you shouldn't instantiate random *inside* of the method. Why are you using default constructor `new Random();` for min value and not pass the actual MinValue to ctor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
Random random = seedValue >= 0 ? new Random(seedValue) : new Random();
```

If you are passing a seed value less than zero, you are not using it at all,
So naturally, the random seed gets selected from the running computer's clock.

Comment: @Repareman Don't worry... Just be careful next time and check it twice before saying: "this and this in .Net isn't working as expected..."

Answer (score 0):

If you check the source code of the `Random` class, you can find the following line in the constructor:

```
int subtraction = (Seed == Int32.MinValue) ?
       Int32.MaxValue : Math.Abs( Seed );
```

This check means that if the `Seed` is equal to `Int32.MinValue`, the `MaxValue` is used instead. It also means the results from both should be exactly the same.

Comment: This is not the case. When I pass in the MinValue I will receive inconsistent results. At one moment it will be 0, and the next it will be 7. (I made up those examples, but it's attempting to further explain the problem.)

Comment: Yes, I would also like to see a sample code that causes this. I am unable to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MartinZikmund: While your code does, apparently, exist (its lifted from the reference source), a quick peek with Reflector yields an entirely different code on my system.  this leads me to believe that the implementation of the Random.ctor that accepts a seed value has changed at least once.  And if its changed once, who knows how many times.  The OP's version of System.Random may be entirely different than yours or mine.